# How to get all the text from a google doc using the ruby api?

Tags: google-docs-api

I am trying to use the Google Ruby API to get all the text from a google doc. Currently on their website it has examples on how to do this using Java and Python, but not ruby.

I am able to get all content from the body using the [following code](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/ruby):

```
document = service.get_document document_id
data = document.body.content
```

This returns a really ugly Google structural element.

Anyone achieved this before, if so how? Any help would be great.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? If so, can you please share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the text of the google doc using the v3 API.

Use the following URL to under the API
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/samples/extract-text#python

Comment: Question was about Ruby, but answer points to Python example.